# SBT default unresolved dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Simple Build Tool (SBT) build and its giving this error, can anyone give me a clue as to why?

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: default#default-44479a_2.9.2;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Looks like you have a dependency on some subproject (and it is not satisfied yet, by doing `publish-local` on it), can you add here or link from somewhere else (gist, pastebin) your build file?

Comment: Yeah, right, what does the build file look like?

Comment: Yes your right, its a dependency which is not working. I never publish-local. Its this Build.scala https://github.com/philip142au/zero/blob/master/project/Build.scala - which is now "working" - you can see the Project close to the end of this file, I have removed the offending dependencies.

Comment: @Phil that link is broken - what was the solution?

Comment: Hi @RobinGreen, sorry I removed the code. I decided that its better that I write small programs with small dependancies which communicate via Akka rather than one large program with a lot of dependancies. In the end, this works as one large program, but it is not. The problem with dependancies is that they sometimes just don't compile together. Its also hard to keep them all up to date.